# video segmentation on mobile devices

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have used tensorflow.js to do person segmentation  of live video in a web browser. Is there a similar tensorflowlite/mobile version of the same? Is there any android SDK available to do person/video segmentation on mobile clients? Any pointers would be very helpful.

thanks
Sowmya

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TensorFlow Lite is available for Android. [Click here for more.](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TensorFlow Lite's Segmentation Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/segmentation/overview). You can see an example GIF on the page also. The segmentation model ( DeepLab v3 ) can segment various objects in an image. Since we are concerned with person segmentation, DeepLabv3 can handle that too.

If you want to use [BodyPix](https://medium.com/tensorflow/introducing-bodypix-real-time-person-segmentation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-f1948126c2a0), which is a TensorFlow.js implementation, you need to find the model's frozen graph along with the input/output nodes. Only then you can get it into TensorFlow Lite. On investigating the repo, I found this [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/body-pix/src/saved_models.ts) which contains the URLs for the model.

Else, we can use [Real-Time Pose Estimation](https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5), which is also a TF JS implementation.

Comment: Tx Shubham, I understand that the segmentation model/DeepLabv3 of TensorFlow Lite is for images. Is there a similar solution in TensorFlow lite that will do person segmentation on video?  I have used BodyPix/TensorFlow.js on web browser and it works well on video. Thanks